# How can I add Track Button to Magento on frontend - Magento 1

Tags: sales, order-history

How can I add track button on sales/order/history/

Comment: Mention the magento version please.

Comment: Sukumar Gorai, sorry. Is magento 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the below file:

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/history.phtml

to your theme(if its not present in your theme location):

> app/design/frontend/[your_package]/[your_theme]/template/sales/order/history.phtml

Find the below block:

```
<?php /*<span class="separator">|</span><a href="<?php echo $this->getTrackUrl($_order) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Track Order') ?></a>&nbsp;*/ ?>
```

and uncomment it:

```
<span class="separator">|</span><a href="<?php echo $this->getTrackUrl($_order) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Track Order') ?></a>&nbsp;
```